# How to import Oracle DMP file without knowing the original tablespace?

Tags: database, oracle, migration, datapump

Use case: customer's will send their backup of their DB in a dmp file. That's all they will send.

I'm building a script that will import that dmp file into Oracle using DBMS_DATAPUMP. However, as I do not know the original tablespace name, I'm getting the following error:
ORA-39083: Object type USER:"XXXXX" failed to create with error:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'XXXXXXX' does not exist

This is my PL/SQL procedure:

```
    PROCEDURE IMPORTING 
(
  DMPFILES IN VARCHAR2,
  FROMSCHEMA IN VARCHAR2,
  TOSCHEMA IN VARCHAR2
) AS
  ind NUMBER;              -- Loop index
  h1 NUMBER;               -- Data Pump job handle
  percent_done NUMBER;     -- Percentage of job complete
  job_state VARCHAR2(30);  -- To keep track of job state
  le ku$_LogEntry;         -- For WIP and error messages
  js ku$_JobStatus;        -- The job status from get_status
  jd ku$_JobDesc;          -- The job description from get_status
  sts ku$_Status;          -- The status object returned by get_status
  array apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
BEGIN
  h1 := DBMS_DATAPUMP.open('IMPORT','FULL',NULL,'EXAMPLE1'); 
  dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'IMPORT.LOG', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => 3);
  -- usign this function to split the files passed as a String to an array
  array  := apex_util.string_to_table(DMPFILES, ',');

  for i in 1 .. array.count loop
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(h1,array(i),'DATA_PUMP_DIR');
  end loop;

  DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_REMAP(h1,'REMAP_SCHEMA',FROMSCHEMA,TOSCHEMA);

dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name =>
'INCLUDE_METADATA', value => 1);
 dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name =>
'DATA_ACCESS_METHOD', value => 'AUTOMATIC');
 dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name =>
'REUSE_DATAFILES', value => 0);
 dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name =>
'SKIP_UNUSABLE_INDEXES', value => 0);

  DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(h1);

-- The import job should now be running. In the following loop, the job is 
-- monitored until it completes. In the meantime, progress information is 
-- displayed. Note: this is identical to the export example.

 percent_done := 0;
  job_state := 'UNDEFINED';
  while (job_state != 'COMPLETED') and (job_state != 'STOPPED') loop
    dbms_datapump.get_status(h1,
           dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error +
           dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_status +
           dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip,-1,job_state,sts);
    js := sts.job_status;

-- If the percentage done changed, display the new value.

     if js.percent_done != percent_done
    then
      dbms_output.put_line('*** Job percent done = ' ||
                           to_char(js.percent_done));
      percent_done := js.percent_done;
    end if;

-- If any work-in-progress (WIP) or Error messages were received for the job,
-- display them.

       if (bitand(sts.mask,dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip) != 0)
    then
      le := sts.wip;
    else
      if (bitand(sts.mask,dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error) != 0)
      then
        le := sts.error;
      else
        le := null;
      end if;
    end if;
    if le is not null
    then
      ind := le.FIRST;
      while ind is not null loop
        dbms_output.put_line(le(ind).LogText);
        ind := le.NEXT(ind);
      end loop;
    end if;
  end loop;

-- Indicate that the job finished and gracefully detach from it. 

  dbms_output.put_line('Job has completed');
  dbms_output.put_line('Final job state = ' || job_state);
  dbms_datapump.detach(h1);
END IMPORTING;
```

So basically my question is:
Is there a way to import a dmp file into Oracle without knowing the original tablespace...?

Thanks in advance for the help.

UPDATE:
I found when using this script, I also need to know the schema name. So that will make the following changes on the script:

```
     PROCEDURE IMPORTING 
(
  DMPFILES IN VARCHAR2,
  FROMSCHEMA IN VARCHAR2,
  TOSCHEMA IN VARCHAR2,
  FROMTABLESPACE IN VARCHAR2,
  TOTABLESPACE IN VARCHAR2
) AS
  ind NUMBER;              -- Loop index
  h1 NUMBER;               -- Data Pump job handle
  percent_done NUMBER;     -- Percentage of job complete
  job_state VARCHAR2(30);  -- To keep track of job state
  le ku$_LogEntry;         -- For WIP and error messages
  js ku$_JobStatus;        -- The job status from get_status
  jd ku$_JobDesc;          -- The job description from get_status
  sts ku$_Status;          -- The status object returned by get_status
  array apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
BEGIN
  h1 := DBMS_DATAPUMP.open('IMPORT','FULL',NULL,'EXAMPLE1'); 
  dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'IMPORT.LOG', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => 3);
  -- usign this function to split the files passed as a String to an array
  array  := apex_util.string_to_table(DMPFILES, ',');

  for i in 1 .. array.count loop
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(h1,array(i),'DATA_PUMP_DIR');
  end loop;

  DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_REMAP(h1,'REMAP_TABLESPACE',FROMTABLESPACE,TOTABLESPACE);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_REMAP(h1,'REMAP_SCHEMA',FROMSCHEMA,TOSCHEMA);

dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name =>
'INCLUDE_METADATA', value => 1);
 dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name =>
'DATA_ACCESS_METHOD', value => 'AUTOMATIC');
 dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name =>
'REUSE_DATAFILES', value => 0);
 dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name =>
'SKIP_UNUSABLE_INDEXES', value => 0);

  DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(h1);

-- The import job should now be running. In the following loop, the job is 
-- monitored until it completes. In the meantime, progress information is 
-- displayed. Note: this is identical to the export example.

 percent_done := 0;
  job_state := 'UNDEFINED';
  while (job_state != 'COMPLETED') and (job_state != 'STOPPED') loop
    dbms_datapump.get_status(h1,
           dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error +
           dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_status +
           dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip,-1,job_state,sts);
    js := sts.job_status;

-- If the percentage done changed, display the new value.

     if js.percent_done != percent_done
    then
      dbms_output.put_line('*** Job percent done = ' ||
                           to_char(js.percent_done));
      percent_done := js.percent_done;
    end if;

-- If any work-in-progress (WIP) or Error messages were received for the job,
-- display them.

       if (bitand(sts.mask,dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip) != 0)
    then
      le := sts.wip;
    else
      if (bitand(sts.mask,dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error) != 0)
      then
        le := sts.error;
      else
        le := null;
      end if;
    end if;
    if le is not null
    then
      ind := le.FIRST;
      while ind is not null loop
        dbms_output.put_line(le(ind).LogText);
        ind := le.NEXT(ind);
      end loop;
    end if;
  end loop;

-- Indicate that the job finished and gracefully detach from it. 

  dbms_output.put_line('Job has completed');
  dbms_output.put_line('Final job state = ' || job_state);
  dbms_datapump.detach(h1);
END IMPORTING;
```

I tested that with a dmp that I exported so I knew the TableSpace and the Schema name.

Summary: any way then to know the tablespace name and the schema name from a dmp file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no

**Long answer: yes** if you generate the ddl file and then you can actually grep the fille and search for the tablespaces and users. See bellow the script to generate the DDL file:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE GENERATE_SQL 
(
  DMPFILES IN VARCHAR2 
, SQLFILENAME IN VARCHAR2 
, VERSIONPARAM IN VARCHAR2 
, JOBNAME IN VARCHAR2 
) AS 
  h1 number;
  array apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
  ind NUMBER;              -- Loop indexdasdads
  percent_done NUMBER;     -- Percentage of job complete
  job_state VARCHAR2(30);  -- To keep track of job state
  le ku$_LogEntry;         -- For WIP and error messages
  js ku$_JobStatus;        -- The job status from get_status
  jd ku$_JobDesc;          -- The job description from get_status
  sts ku$_Status;          -- The status object returned by get_status
BEGIN
  h1 := dbms_datapump.open(
    operation    => 'SQL_FILE',
    job_mode     => 'SCHEMA',
    remote_link  =>  null,
    job_name     => JOBNAME,
    version      => VERSIONPARAM
  );
  array  := apex_util.string_to_table(DMPFILES, ',');
  for i in 1 .. array.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line('array(i): ' || array(i));
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(h1,array(i),'DBRAT_DMP',dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('datapump_job: ' || h1);

  dbms_datapump.add_file(
    handle    =>  h1,
    filename  => SQLFILENAME,
    directory => 'DBRAT_DMP',
    filetype  =>  dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_sql_file);

  dbms_datapump.start_job(
    handle       => h1,
    skip_current => 0,
    abort_step   => 0);

  percent_done := 0;
  job_state := 'UNDEFINED';
  while (job_state != 'COMPLETED') and (job_state != 'STOPPED') loop
    dbms_datapump.get_status(h1,
           dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error +
           dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_status +
           dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip,-1,job_state,sts);
    js := sts.job_status;

-- If the percentage done changed, display the new value.

     if js.percent_done != percent_done
    then
      dbms_output.put_line('*** Job percent done = ' ||
                           to_char(js.percent_done));
      percent_done := js.percent_done;
    end if;

-- If any work-in-progress (WIP) or Error messages were received for the job,
-- display them.

       if (bitand(sts.mask,dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip) != 0)
    then
      le := sts.wip;
    else
      if (bitand(sts.mask,dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error) != 0)
      then
        le := sts.error;
      else
        le := null;
      end if;
    end if;
    if le is not null
    then
      ind := le.FIRST;
      while ind is not null loop
        dbms_output.put_line(le(ind).LogText);
        ind := le.NEXT(ind);
      end loop;
    end if;
  end loop;

-- Indicate that the job finished and gracefully detach from it. 

  dbms_output.put_line('Job has completed');
  dbms_output.put_line('Final job state = ' || job_state);
  dbms_datapump.detach(h1);
END GENERATE_SQL;
```